# How to display original unmodified thumbnail

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, gallery

I have uploaded a few images that are being used as thumbnails. I cropped them within WordPress to be square and focus on the subject of the image. I have also got a slider that is rectangular and shows one image at a time.

At the moment the sliders displays each posts thumbnail which is square and modified. I was wondering how you can display each posts original uploaded image for the thumbnail and if this is even possible.

This is all on the homepage.

Any help and advice welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Thumbnail functions accept a size parameter, the original size can be accessed via `full` :

```
the_post_thumbnail('full');
```